# What is the correct (most common) translation for 'damas'?

Tags: traducción, definiciones, juegos

I've just come across the word '*damas*', I intended to use the word in reference to a group of women but I see it also translates to 'checkers'?!

Does the word have different meanings depending on location? Where is the correlation between women and checkers?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Damas* means "ladies" or "dames". It's a bit old-fashioned. You'll find it in the stock phrase *"damas y caballeros"* ("ladies and gentlemen"), but this kind of thing is on its way out. You'll also see *damas* as a label for bathrooms. You can often substitute *señoras*. Unlike *señora(s)*, you cannot use *dama(s)* as a vocative (i.e. to call or address someone) by itself.

*Damas* is also the name of the [game of checkers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draughts#Crowning). *Dama* is also one of the names (besides *reina*) for the queen in the game of chess. The pieces of checkers were originally named in French *fierges*, the same as the chess queen (for Persian *ferz* "vizier"); when the queen changed its name to *dame* the checkers pieces took it as well.

Answer (score 7):

I would say that there are two posibilities. First of all, if you want to mean a group of women, I would say 'ladies'. Secondly, 'damas' is also a board game called checkers. The word has both meanings.

For more information, this is valid in Spain.